# Django - multiple files at once upload form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm searching for a module which allows me to create a file upload form using which I can upload multiple files at once.

I've found [Django-Uploadify](https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify/tree/master/uploadify) but it seems to be deprecated - last commits has been done 4 - 7 years ago.

Do you know some up-to-date module which allows multiple file upload?

Comment: http://chive.ch/django-multiupload/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multi-upload in standard Django:

```
for f in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
    #do something with f
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to select every file separately (for x files I have to use x forms), haven't I? The main thing is to make uploading more comfortable.

Comment: Wait, so you want to store all the files in the same model field? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: In fact, I probably will not use database at all. The thing is that I upload for example 100 small CSV files and they will be instantly converted into graphs. After that, they will be removed. It's very uncomfortable upload all those files one by one so that's why I want to select them all and upload them in one time.

Comment: I don't follow. If you're not using a db, where are you uploading them to?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that it's just being hold in memory. You can upload a file, then for example count a number of words and return this number and you don't need to explicitly saving it into the database.

Comment: So you can store all of the files in different variables, or in a list, and handle each as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I didn`t want to do in in view, so I did it in such case.

```
class MultipleFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self):
        files = []

        if not 'file' in self.files:
            return files

        for single_file in self.files.getlist('file'):
            file = self.Meta.model(
                file=single_file,
            )
            file.save()
            files.append(file)

        return files

    class Meta(object):
        model = FileModel
        fields = ["file"]
        widgets = {
            'file': forms.FileInput(attrs={
                'multiple': True,
            }),
        }
```